# Constructing objects while adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, object, constructor, arraylist, tostring

```
public class ComputerKit {
private ArrayList <ComputerPart> parts = new ArrayList();
//constructor
public ComputerKit(ComputerPart ... cp){
    for(int x=0;x<cp.length;x++){
        parts.add(x, cp);

    }
}

//method toString
@Override
public String toString(){
    String s = parts.get(0).toString();

    return s;
}
```

I'm trying to add ComputerPart objects to an arraylist in the constructor of ComputerKit. I want to be able to add as many ComputerParts to the ComputerKit as I want. Here is the relevant code for ComputerPart:

```
public class ComputerPart {
//two instance variables representing a computerpart
private String item;
private double price;
//constructor
public ComputerPart(String i, double p){
    setItem(i);
    setPrice(p);
}
```

My problem, I think, is that the compiler doesn't know how to add a ComputerPart specifically. It can add an Object but if I leave it as a general object, then when I call parts.get(x).toString() I won't get the item and price private variables in String type.

I'm gonna keep working on it hopefully I figure it out in 3 hours when its due lololol!
Thanks!!

Comment: `cp` contains *all* the computer parts, so you are adding them all to your list several times.

Comment: Also, you can override the `toString()` method in `ComputerPart` in order to give whatever output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line should give compiler error since your ArrayList is taking a ComputerPart object whereas in the code you are adding an array.

```
 parts.add(x, cp);
```

Change it to

```
 parts.add(x, cp[x]);
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, this instantly solved it. You are my savior, I will follow you to the depths of hell. Thanks man! I wasn't getting a compiler error though. The toString() would just output the Object.toString() (the default object one)

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList <ComputerPart> parts = new ArrayList<>();
```

You should be getting a compiler warning with your original line.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine. How are you trying to call the `ComputerKit` constructor that isn't working for you? The one thing you should change is how the parts are added to the list:

```
public ComputerKit(ComputerPart ... cp){
    for(ComputerPart part : cp){
        parts.add(cp);
    }
}
```

and if you're feeling super-smart, change the declared type from `ArrayList` to `List`:

```
private List<ComputerPart> parts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private ArrayList<ComputerPart> parts;
//Constructor
public ComputerKit(ComputerPart... cp){
    parts = new ArrayList<ComputerPart>(Arrays.asList(cp));
}
```

Also, you should be overriding `toString()` in `ComputerPart` unless you want the default object String representation. Something like

```
public String toString(){
    return item + " " + price;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I suppose that was a relevant code portion I left out, heh. I did override the toString() for the ComputerPart. Thanks!